# How to efficiently find a running latest update for multiple records in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, optimization

Consider the following schema,

```
-- items which have periodic updates
CREATE TABLE items (
  [id] int identity(1, 1) primary key,
  [name] varchar(100) not null
);

-- item updates. updating an item generally means it has a new status, at a certain time.
CREATE TABLE updates (
  [id] int identity(1, 1) primary key,
  [item_id] int foreign key references items([id]),
  [new_status] varchar(100) not null,
  [update_date] datetime not null
);
```

which is used to track the state of an item, through many states, over time.

I've been trying to find an efficient query that will answer the following question:

> For many items, which can be in one of several states, where we log status updates, how many items are currently in each state at the end of each day?

I have an SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d04fa/2), which has a bit of sample data, and my current attempt at this query.
It runs fine on a few items, but my database has hundreds of thousands, and so my query currently takes about 5 minutes to run.

Is there a more efficient query to answer this question?

**Test data:**

```
-- items which have periodic updates
CREATE TABLE items (
  [id] int identity(1, 1) primary key,
  [name] varchar(100) not null
);

-- item updates. updating an item generally means it has a new status, at a certain time.
CREATE TABLE updates (
  [id] int identity(1, 1) primary key,
  [item_id] int foreign key references items([id]),
  [new_status] varchar(100) not null,
  [update_date] datetime not null
);

-- lets just say that we just created 3 new items
INSERT INTO items (name)
  VALUES ('item1'), ('item2'), ('item3');

-- and they all start in the new state
INSERT INTO updates (item_id, new_status, update_date)
SELECT
  [id],
  [new_status] = 'new',
  [update_date] = '2017-10-9 00:00:00.000'
FROM items

-- then we have them update over the course of a couple days
-- item 1
INSERT INTO updates (item_id, new_status, update_date)
SELECT [id], [new_status] = 'in progress', [update_date] = '2017-10-10 00:00:00.000'
FROM items WHERE [name] = 'item1'
UNION
SELECT [id], [new_status] = 'ready', [update_date] = '2017-10-12 00:00:00.000'
FROM items WHERE [name] = 'item1'
UNION
SELECT [id], [new_status] = 'complete', [update_date] = '2017-10-14 00:00:00.000'
FROM items WHERE [name] = 'item1';

-- item 2
INSERT INTO updates (item_id, new_status, update_date)
SELECT [id], [new_status] = 'in progress', [update_date] = '2017-10-10 00:00:00.000'
FROM items WHERE [name] = 'item2'
UNION
SELECT [id], [new_status] = 'ready', [update_date] = '2017-10-11 00:00:00.000'
FROM items WHERE [name] = 'item2'
UNION
SELECT [id], [new_status] = 'complete', [update_date] = '2017-10-12 00:00:00.000'
FROM items WHERE [name] = 'item2';

-- item 3
INSERT INTO updates (item_id, new_status, update_date)
SELECT [id], [new_status] = 'in progress', [update_date] = '2017-10-11 00:00:00.000'
FROM items WHERE [name] = 'item3'
UNION
SELECT [id], [new_status] = 'ready', [update_date] = '2017-10-13 00:00:00.000'
FROM items WHERE [name] = 'item3'
UNION
SELECT [id], [new_status] = 'complete', [update_date] = '2017-10-15 00:00:00.000'
FROM items WHERE [name] = 'item3';
```

**Current Query:**

```
-- =======================
--  Running latest record
-- =======================
-- Goal: For a period of time, with multiple items, which have multiple updates,
--       find the number of items which are in each state at the end of a day.
-- 
-- Issue: how can i improve this query for a large database?
-- 

SELECT
  dates.[update_date],
  state = latest_update.[new_status],
  volume = COUNT(*)
FROM items i -- start with the items that we want to count per day
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT [update_date] FROM updates
) dates -- the days to count for
CROSS APPLY (
  -- this cross apply gets all updates for an item, that occurred on or before each date
  SELECT
    updates.*,
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [item_id] ORDER BY [update_date] DESC)
  FROM updates
  WHERE [update_date] <= dates.[update_date] AND [item_id] = i.[id]
) latest_update
WHERE latest_update.RN = 1 -- only count the latest update
GROUP BY dates.[update_date], latest_update.[new_status]
ORDER BY dates.[update_date], latest_update.[new_status]
```

**[Results]**:

```
|          update_date |       state | volume |
|----------------------|-------------|--------|
| 2017-10-09T00:00:00Z |         new |      3 |
| 2017-10-10T00:00:00Z | in progress |      2 |
| 2017-10-10T00:00:00Z |         new |      1 |
| 2017-10-11T00:00:00Z | in progress |      2 |
| 2017-10-11T00:00:00Z |       ready |      1 |
| 2017-10-12T00:00:00Z |    complete |      1 |
| 2017-10-12T00:00:00Z | in progress |      1 |
| 2017-10-12T00:00:00Z |       ready |      1 |
| 2017-10-13T00:00:00Z |    complete |      1 |
| 2017-10-13T00:00:00Z |       ready |      2 |
| 2017-10-14T00:00:00Z |    complete |      2 |
| 2017-10-14T00:00:00Z |       ready |      1 |
| 2017-10-15T00:00:00Z |    complete |      3 |
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: plus 1 for sample data,going forward please include expected result as text  as well

Comment: The fiddle has the expected output in the query side. The question is more about how to get the correct answer efficiently for a large number of items.

Answer (score 3):

One method is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select cast(update_date as date), status, count(*)
from (select u.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cast(update_date as date) order by update_date desc) as seqnum
      from updates u
     ) u
where seqnum = 1
group by cast(update_date as date)
order by cast(update_date as date), count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Your query will count the number of updates per day, not the most recent update before a day. I.e. if something is new for 4 consecutive days, then your solution will report new for the first day, then nothing for the next 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY clause at the end of the statement below groups the data in the new_status column according to their values. The database then presents the user with a list of 'distinct' values from the new_status column.

```
select new_status,count(new_status) from updates group by new_status
```

In other words, if we were to run the query without the count(new_status) part then it would be exactly the same as saying:

```
select distinct new_status from updates
```

Because we are asking for a count, the database is able to count how many iterations of each distinct value it has grouped together and present these in the count(new_status) column. As it is the database will not give a name to the column which counts the grouped update values but you can do that like this:

```
select new_status,count(new_status) as nmbr_items from updates group by new_status
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations to your answer?

Comment: Yes I've seen your request for some explanations and I will do that as soon as I can.